# Trouble trimming trailing comma from dynamically filled string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, checkbox

I am trying to trim the last character from a paragraph that I am dynamically filling with checkbox values. The trouble is that I must trim the trailing character of the whole paragraph. I do not want to trim it from the value before it is added to the list of values.

Here is a codepen:

http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/PqLwKJ

HTML:

```
<dl class="dropdown"> 

<dt>
<a href="#">
  <span class="hida">▼</span>     
</a>
</dt>

<dd>
    <div class="mutliSelect">
        <ul class="ul">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="PONumber" />Number</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="AuthNumber" />Auth Number</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="StatusId" />Status</li>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="ManufacturerId" />Manufacturer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</dd>
</dl>
<p class="multiSel"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").slideToggle('fast');
  });

  $(".dropdown dd ul li a").on('click', function () {
      $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  function getSelectedValue(id) {
       return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
  }

  $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
      var $clicked = $(e.target);
      if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown")) $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });


  $('.mutliSelect input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function () {

      var title = $(this).closest('.mutliSelect').find('input[type="checkbox"]').val(),
          title = $(this).val() + ",";

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var html = '<span title="' + title + '">' + title + '</span>';
          $('.multiSel').append(html);
      } 
      else {
          $('span[title="' + title + '"]').remove();
          var ret = $(".hida");
          $('.dropdown dt a').append(ret);

      }
  });
```

There are a bunch of questions about trimming trailing characters on here, but I can't figure out how to trim the paragraph as a whole after a value is dynamically added. Thanks!

Comment: Is [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) helpful? Honestly, this is a really weird way of doing this. Why don't the commas go outside of the title? Now your attribute `title` has a comma inside of it!

Comment: I was just trying to put a comma between each checkbox value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you want. I moved the comma outside the `<span>`

```
$('p.multiSel')
    .html($(this)
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
        .map(function(idx, elem) {
            return $(elem).parent().text().trim();
        })
        .get()
        .map(function(text) {
            return "<span title='" + text + "'>" + text + "</span>";
        })
        .join(', '));
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGBbeO)

### Explanation

```
$('p.multiSel').html(...)
```

([.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) Sets the contents of `<p class='multiSel'>`.

```
$(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

([.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)) Gets the checked check boxes.

```
.map(...)
```

([.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/)) Maps the array of checked check boxes to their plain text, with whitespace trimmed.

```
.get()
```

([.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)) Turns a jQuery selection into a regular array.

```
.map(...)
```

([Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) Maps the plain text into the element you wanted to make by wrapping it in `<span>` tags and stuff.

```
.join(...)
```

([Array.prototype.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) Inserts commas and spaces between all elements of the array we were working on.